# How to magnify an image programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, image, zooming

I have couple of images showing on Android 2.2 with help of PageViewer (Thanks to supporting libs from android). This works like a charm. But what I am looking for is to magnify each of image (zoom in) when they are displayed automatically/programmatically (Not when the user pinch the image). How can I do this?

I saw this feature on Flickr app of iPhone (this feature is not on Android Flickr app).

Answer (score 0):

Use a good size on the ImageView of each item (match_parent, match_parent) and use `android:scaleType=`'centerCrop' or 'centerInside'